# Do the PPS fast charging and USB PD standards only specify USB-C cables?

Tags: usb, usb-c, charger

I'm shopping for a USB charger: I am trying to buy a USB charger that supports the PPS fast charging and USB PD standards, however all such the USB chargers I could find so far have a USB-C output and not USB-A.

Do the PPS fast charging and USB PD standards only specify USB-C cables? Or can a male-to-male USB-C to USB-A cable only support PPS and PD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot possibly do PD, including PPS, over a Type-A connector. USB-PD requires communication over the CC pins that are present in a Type-C connector but absent in a Type-A connector.

A-to-C cables source a fixed current on the CC pins (via a pull-up resistor inside the C end of the cable) to indicate the max current supply ability of the A end. This can indicate one of three current limits: 3.0 A @ 5 V, 1.5 A @ 5 V, or "default USB power" (500 mA @ 5 V, negotiated in 100 mA increments, for USB 2.0). *This is not USB-PD.* USB-PD uses a complex negotiation that is not possible without the CC pins being connected end to end.

Actually, an A-to-C cable should *only* indicate "default USB power" (usually via the somewhat well known 56 kOhm resistor pull-up to 5 V); 3.0 A and 1.5 A can be indicated by the other end of a Type-C cable, whether a captive cable or via C-to-C, but to do so for A-to-C is wrong: there is no way to guarantee a user would not plug such an A-to-C cable into a source not actually capable of those supply currents.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I've added some more info, I forgot that A-to-C should never indicate 1.5A/3.0A via the CC pins.

Answer (score 2):

Under the USB specifications USB-PD required USB-C since version 2.0.  USB-PD version 1.0 allowed for USB-PD over USB-A but I don't recall seeing any products on the market that support this.  Since USB-PD 3.0 use of USB-PD on USB-A is somewhere between discouraged and simply no longer supported.

If we look back at the history of power supplied by USB we will see that USB-PD was late to the party.  Different manufacturers developed means to get more power through USB-A that were incompatible with USB-PD.  When USB-PD came out manufacturers worked on different ways to span that gap between their power deliver scheme and USB-PD.  This means you will find USB-A power supplies and cables that will "talk" USB-PD out the USB-C end of the cable.  This often requires using a translator cable, a cable that looks like a USB cable but is in fact not compliant with the USB spec because it has electronics in it that prevent USB signals passing through.

I realize this can be quite confusing, and unfortunately it will remain confusing until the markets settles on how power is to be delivered by USB and incompatible devices die off and end up in the recycling bin.

I didn't mention USB-PPS until this point because USB-PPS is part of the USB-PD 3.0 protocol (perhaps I'm mistaken and it came out earlier with 2.0).  For anything to support USB-PPS they must support USB-PD.  To get USB-PD, at least any version beyond the rare as hen teeth 1.0, means USB-C

There are power supply and cable combinations that will combine their own power delivery protocol, USB-PD/PPS, with a USB-A to USB-C translator cable.  These products will support both their proprietary power delivery protocol and USB-PD/PPS on USB-C (or in some cases a halfway compatible subset of USB-PD/PPS).

Personally I try to avoid products that violate the USB spec, and recommend you do the same.  I've seen people let the magic smoke of some expensive hardware because of devices that decided to go outside the USB spec.

How do you know a product is not up to the USB spec?  Look for the USB trademarked symbols and iconography.  It's not illegal to make products that look like USB but break the spec, it is however illegal to claim they follow the spec but do not.  This makes products that violate the spec and have the USB trademarks short lived on the market and therefore quite rare.

The USB spec says that USB-PPS is only to be used on USB-C so start there in looking for compatible chargers.  Then look for the USB trademark.  It would not hurt to also look for things like UL listing and FCC compliance as that gives greater assurance the product won't damage your hardware or go up in smoke.